# How to delete sonarqube branches in database

Tags: sonarqube

I have a sonar dashboard which has projects on branch level. Most of the Sonar branches(projects) are not used now.

I have written a script to clean-up the branches in sonar which works fine but the branch details in sonar database were never removed.

Please let me know the best way to remove the deleted projects in sonar database as there branches are of a lot older releases and will never be analysed again

Comment: What does your script do to clean-up the branches? I think if you delete a sonar project from the server settings page (requires admin privileges), it should take care of the clean-up...

Comment: My script calls the sonar rest api to delete branches. The scripts get all the projects from sonar, check if it is a branch and checks for the last modified time. If it is older than 30 days or so it removes the branch by calling /api/projects/destroy

Answer (score 0):

You should never directly alter the database. Note that there's a bulk deletion feature that can be useful in your case: http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Project+Existence#ProjectExistence-Deletion

Comment: I am not planning to alter the database but once the projects were removed in sonar, they are not visible in "Bulk Deletion" as well. I think only the database has the references.

Comment: The Link does not work anymore... :-(